# AWS - adminGetUser returns unexpected error

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a problem when trying to connect to my AWS cognito database. 
Here is my code:

```
 AWS.config.region = 'eu-west-2'; // Region
 AWS.config.accessKeyId = 'XXXXXXXXXX';
 AWS.config.secretAccessKey = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX';
 AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
     IdentityPoolId: 'eu-west-2:XXXX-XXXXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXXX',
 }); 

 var params = {
      UserPoolId: 'eu-west-2_xxxxxxxxxx',
      Username: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
 };

 var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();

 cognitoidentityserviceprovider.adminGetUser(params, function(err, data) {
          if (err) console.log(err); // an error occurred
          else     console.log(data);           // successful response
 })
```

Here is a breakdown -

At first I am configure the AWS.config with the *region*, *accessKeyID*, *secretAccessKey* and the credentials with `AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials()`.

I then simply set a new `AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider()` variable and call the `adminGetUSer` function with the *UserPoolID* and *Username* parameters (the Username is the username of the user I want to get information of)

However, I am getting a very weird error when deploying it: 
[image]

"Cannot read property 'byteLength' of undefined..

When looking at the http request: 
[image]

And the response is a little weird looking: 
[image]

Thank you for your time reading this! Hope someone would be able to help me understand what is the problem with my code.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

can you please post the statement that the stack trace originates from?

Also, are you using the 'aws-sdk' version provided by aws-amplify?

The response definitely looks incorrect and does not match the [Response specified by the AdminGetUser API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_AdminGetUser.html). I think you're looking at the wrong entry in your network tab.